# rails - fragment caching in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching

Is there a way to enable fragment caching in development mode?  I would like fragment caching enabled but when I do so it appears to also cache controller pages and assets, which I do not want cached.

```
config.action_controller.cache_store = [:file_store,"#{Rails.root}/tmp/cache"]
```